# SCD Type 2 by Merge Statement for tracking changes for Joined Table without unique Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, scd

I have a table for which I want to create `SCD Type 2` by using the `T-SQL Merge statement`, however it doesn't have a unique key.

```
RoleTaskTable:
RoleID, TaskID
1,A
1,B
1,C
2,A
2,D
2,F
3,A
3,B
3,E
3,F
```

Obviously I get the error

```
"The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows."
```

When I combine `RoleID` and `TaskID` as the unique index for the Staging Table as well as the SCDTable, it will recognize it simply as a new record, thus all records (even if some are deleted) stay flagged as Active in the SCD table.

How can you solve something like this?

I can in case show the entire code I have for this SCD, but I think I miss something basic here.

Answer (score 0):

A the risk of sounding obvious, give the table a unique key.  Without one it is not a proper relation.  Merge is designed to work work unique keys.

OTOH, since Merge is just a one-stop-shop for insert/update/delete, you could use the individual commands, wrapped in a transaction, to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Is it a good idea then to give the table a unique RowNumber that can never be changed, so if records are deleted, it will continue counting with the highest digit ever used?

Comment: That can be good, but probably won't do for the OPs MERGE statement, which needs to look at business keys.